# jwplayer, Play from playlist when streaming is not available

Tags: streaming, webcam, jwplayer, live-streaming

I am streaming a live webcam using jwplayer. I want to play advertisement from playlist when the streaming is not available. Here is my code for showing the live streaming. Can anyone help?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'type': 'rtmp',
    'streamer': 'rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo',
    'autostart': 'true',
    'bufferlength': '3',
    'file': 'aaa',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '320',
    'height': '260'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If a stream is down, you can use our JS API, and the onError Event, to do something like this - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It's use JwPlayer 6

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'autostart': 'true',
    'bufferlength': '3',
    'file': 'aaa',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '320',
    'height': '260',
    playlist: [{
sources: [{ 
//First video
   file: "rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo"
},{
//alternative video
file: "http://180.244.230.232:5080/live/streams/test.m3u8"
        }]
    }],
  });
</script>
```